# language problem, when navigating to another page does not use the last selected language

Tags: wordpress, multilingual, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a problem with translation, I use the translate press plugin with 2 languages, ID and EN I use manual translation not automatic, so the case when changed using the switcher can change per page, but not when from the beginning on the home page I change using EN when moving the page to the product will return to the ID language

I have changed the permalink, and tried to use opposite and currentlanguage, I want when the last language is selected ID then when switching pages it will use ID continuously, if using EN then using EN when switching pages.